# Few questions about developing custom Payment Gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, payment-gateway, core-config-data, increment-id

I am creating a custom payment module using Paypal API(Don't want to use any Magento Paypal Module).
I have 2 question while developing the custom module. Please help me to solve it.

1. My logic is as follows: From magento default cart when a user click check out it is redirecting to my custom module for proceeding to payment using Paypal. Now after successful payment I need increment id to insert the order record in the order table . But how can I get the new increment id for the new order? This is my first question.
2. After payment, magento storing the payment details in `sales_order_payment` table. It is storing the payment type in the 'method' field of the table, like `ccsave`,`checkmo`. These name are coming from the `core_config_data` table(which are storing from `config.xml` file of the module).  But I cannot add my module to the config table(I wrote payment details in `config.xml` file). That's why while I add my custom payment type to the 'method' field of `sales_order_payment` table, It is not detecting my payment module.
   I am adding my `config.xml` file content here:

`

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Payment_Form>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Payment_Form>
    </modules>   
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <JustSomeFreeRouterNameHereNo1>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Payment_Form</module>
                    <frontName>payment-form</frontName>
                </args>
            </JustSomeFreeRouterNameHereNo1>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <form>
                <active>1</active>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>CUSTOM CARD</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </form>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Please help me solving this 2 issues.

Answer (score 1):

for first one you just for getting the order id

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

for second part

```
        <form>
            <model>modulename/standard</model>
            <active>1</active>
            <order_status>pending</order_status>
            <title>CUSTOM CARD</title>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </form>
```

model code code

```
    class Spacename_Moduelname_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

protected $_code = 'youpaymentmodulecode'; // this code will be saved in core_config_data

protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
protected $_canUseInternal          = false;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;

/**
* Return Order place redirect url
*
* @return string
*/
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
//when you click on place order you will be redirected on this url, if you don't want this action remove this method
return Mage::getUrl('redirectpath', array('_secure' => true));
}
public function isAvailable($quote = NULL)
{
    return true;
} 

}
```

Comment: `$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();` this code not showing any data.

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe did you using this after the order placed?

Comment: I searched in the session.php page in checkout model .But there is no function named getLastOrderId()‌​. I think thats why it is not returning any value. can you share your checkout/session.php page or the getLastOrderId()‌​ function?

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe this is session not the method read about magento session how to set session and how to retrieve it. you can set session 
`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setLastOrderId('fdfd')‌​;` and get `$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()‌​;`

Comment: Ok. I will check that . For second part can you tell me a small part of your answer? first I will add the code block within `<form>``</form>` in the 'config.xml' file. But after that where I will add the the second part of the code? i.e model code.

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe `Spacename/Moduelname/Model/Standard.php` i think it is more clear in class name.

Comment: hi, 1st part is working. But second part is not working. I added the content in config.xml file and in model file too. But there is no change in database. @Qaisar Satti

Comment: did you define model or just put `<model>Spacename_Moduelname_Model_Standard</model>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44511/discussion-between-subhajyoti-de-and-qaisar-satti).